# Passing column to when function in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have two pyspark dataframes:

1st dataframe: **plants**

```
 +-----+--------+
 |plant|station |
 +-----+--------+
 |Kech |    st1 |
 |Casa |    st2 |
 +-----+--------+
```

2nd dataframe: **stations**

```
 +-------+--------+
 |program|station |
 +-------+--------+
 |pr1    |    null|
 |pr2    |    st1 |
 +-------+--------+
```

What i want is to replace the null values in the second dataframe stations with all the column station in the first dataframe. Like this :

```
+-------+--------------+
|program|station       |
+-------+--------------+
|pr1    |    [st1, st2]|
|pr2    |    st1       |
+-------+--------------+
```

I did this:

```
stList = plants.select(F.col('station')).rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()
stations = stations.select(
                    F.col('program')
                    F.when(stations.station.isNull(), stList).otherwise(stations.station).alias('station')
)
```

but it gives me an error when doesn't accept python list as a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies.

I've found the solution by converting the column to pandas.

```
stList = list(plants.select(F.col('station')).toPandas()['station'])
```

and then use:

```
F.when(stations.station.isNull(), F.array([F.lit(x) for x in station])).otherwise(stations['station']).alias('station')
```

**it gives directly an array.**

Answer (score -1):

quick work around is 
`F.lit(str(stList))`
this should work.
For better type casting use below mentioned code.

```
stations = stations.select(
                    F.col('program'),
                    F.when(stations.station.isNull(), func.array([func.lit(x) for x in stList]))
.otherwise(func.array(stations.station)).alias('station')
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you can't keep different datatypes in station column, it needs to be consistent.

```
+-------+--------------+
|program|station       |
+-------+--------------+
|pr1    |    [st1, st2]| # this is array
|pr2    |    st1       | # this is string
+-------+--------------+
```

Secondly, this should do the trick:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Create the stList as a string.
stList = ",".join(plants.select(F.col('station')).rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()) 

# coalesce the variables and then apply pyspark.sql.functions.split function
stations = (stations.select(
    F.col('program'),
    F.split(F.coalesce(stations.station, F.lit(stList)), ",").alias('station')))
stations.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+----------+
|program|   station|
+-------+----------+
|    pr1|[st1, st2]|
|    pr2|     [st1]|
+-------+----------+
```